# How to check whether DVD-writer's firmware being changed

Tags: 16.04

Suddenly I found the rarely used DVD-writer couldn't be ejected by all means. e.g.

```
$ eject
eject: unable to eject, last error: Inappropriate ioctl for device

$ eject -t
eject: CD-ROM tray close command failed: Input/output error
```

How can I check whether its firmware could have been accidentally flashed during the package `linux-firmware` was being updated?

Comment: Stick the end of a paper clip into the tiny little whole on the tray?

Comment: No luck, it's not jammed.

Comment: linux-firmware couldn't have caused this problem. The paper clip trick should manually get your CD/DVD out of the drive. Explain your configuration... internal/external DVD? USB, ATA, or SATA DVD drive?